# Illustrator: how to apply graphic styles to multiple objects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow, graphic-styles

Is it possible to apply graphic styles to multiple object or even for whole layer in Illustrator?

Adobe's [website](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/graphic-styles.html) says the following about applying the graphic style:

> Select an object or group (or target a layer in the Layers panel).

But no matter how I try to use groups, applying is now working as said. And even so, it feels an extra step always group objects before applying styles to multiple objects.

Comment: You don't ***have to*** group them, just make a multiple selection.

Answer (score 1):

- Lock every other layer via the 'Layers' panel, only keeping your current layer unlocked.
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to unlock any locked objects on your current layer.
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to 'Select All' and click the style you need, which will apply to everything selected.

Comment: Damn, I have always dragged graphic styles rather than just clicking them. LOL xD Adobes User Guide is incomplete in this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielCookie have you actually read it form cover to cover (or page for page)? I have

Comment: Nope, so you are right! But that´s not how user guides are read at first place. I read section Create special effects - About graphic styles - Apply a graphic style and it tells only about dragging method. But yeah, I should realize that buttons can be clicked too, so who conversation on useless.

Comment: @DanielCookie Thats what you think, youd be surprised how much you can get done by atleast skimreading each page

Comment: @DanielCookie Actually they do mention selecting style to apply it. Just above telling how to drag in the page https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/graphic-styles.html

Comment: There you are absolutely right. I should go through the whole guide. Nowadays a web tutorial based learning is so general that If instructor don´t show something you assume that it is not there xD I heed your advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. However there is a trick to select layers, groups or other compound items you need to press the small circle next to the name in layers panel! This is admittedly a bit quirky as highlighting does not select objects, but activates the layer objects for object insertion.

[image]

**Image 1**: To select a layer you need to press the circle not layer name

You can now apply effects to the layer as a whole (this will be applied on top or below the objects own effects depending on where the group is) in the appearance panel. Since layers have this extra contents item it may need to be created from from scratch or modified so contents is in right place after applying style.

This also works as indicator on if layer has any effects. See the circle gets filled once it has a effect applied.

Comment: Now I know what _(or target a layer in the Layers panel)_ means!  Thanks!